# Need to check the specific cell value from a table in selenium

Tags: selenium

Need to check the specific cell value from a table in selenium.
As per the GUI view it is the 5th column of 1st Row and I need to keep reading the value of this cell until it changes to some other state from in progress state.Following is the XML:

```
<html>
<head><style>
BODY
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 8pt;
    scrollbar-face-color: #666699;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #c2c8e2;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #c2c8e2;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #666699;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #666699;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #e6eef7;
    scrollbar-track-color: #e6eef7;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
TD
{
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 8pt;
}

</style></head>
<body topMargin="0" leftMargin="0" onload="javascript:OnLoad();" onunload="javascript:closeWin();"><div id="divMainTbl" style="width: 1358px; height: 182px; overflow: auto; position: relative;" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0"><form name="frmDSV" id="frmDSV" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" action="/epace/epace-cgi/pacecgi.exe?sessionid=" method="post" target="ifChildEvents"><table width="100%" id="tblQ" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" nowrap="" xmlns:user="" xmlns:msxsl=""><tbody><tr style="background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);">

<td noWrap="">
 &nbsp;In Progress&nbsp;&nbsp;
</td>

</tr></tbody></table></form></div></body></html>
```

---

```
<DIV id="divMainTbl" style='position: 
<TABLE id="tblQ" WIDTH="100&#37" BOR>
  <TR> 
    -- Column <tds
  </TR>
  <tr style="background-color:#F1F1F1;">
    <td class="HU2">&nbsp;1&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap width="2&#37" height="15" </td>
    <td nowrap>&nbsp;Positions&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap>&nbsp;Data Upload&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap>&nbsp;Completed&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: Which value you want to capture? And, I guess you meant to say `html` not `xml` ?

Comment: Yes HTML, I need the Xpath of this cell which contains "In Progress" value in above HTML.

Comment: Well to capture `In Progress`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that's the only `td` you have. If so it's fairly easy.

```
 //div[@id='divMainTbl']//td
```

Since the `div` has an `id` it easier to start from there and find the ONLY `td` accordingly.

Comment: Actually this is 2nd <tr of this table first <tr having all column names and from 2nd <tr onward values and this particular cell is 5th <td of 2nd <tr.Please suggest.

Comment: I actually see only one `tr` here. Can you please verify the `html`?

Comment: Removed some part as it was too long but this is the structure of the HTML,you can see after the Div ,table is there then <TR for column and then for value, in this HTML status value is Completed as it has changed : <DIV id="divMainTbl" style='position: 
<TABLE id="tblQ" WIDTH="100&#37" BOR>
  <TR> 
    -- Column <tds
  </TR>
  <tr style="background-color:#F1F1F1;">
    <td class="HU2">&nbsp;1&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap width="2&#37" height="15" </td>
    <td nowrap>&nbsp;Positions&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap>&nbsp;Data Upload&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap>&nbsp;Completed&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

Comment: Added the HTML is main post as well

Comment: @Ashish So you want the `td` that has text `Completed`?

Comment: I need to keep checking for the <td which initially will be having the value in-progress and until it changes to completed or some other status,Also this is not the only row in the table but yes I need the value only from the first row.

Comment: Is it the same `td` whose text are changing?

Comment: yes this td value is changing & Initially the value will be in progress for few minutes and I need to keep checking the value until it changes from in progress to something else

Comment: @Ashish Try `TABLE[id='tblQ'] tr td:last-child` notice this is `cssSelector`